# AWK print lines between two patterns, only need to print last occurrence of matching lines

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to filter a log file and print some lines between two matches and print only the last occurrence.

Sample file content:

```
2023-03-08 11:12:44,306 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-08 11:12:44,306 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-08 11:12:44,306 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-08 11:12:44,307 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-08 11:13:31,782 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_12
2023-03-08 11:13:31,783 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_13
2023-03-08 11:13:32,553 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-08 11:13:32,554 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
2023-03-08 11:13:34,900 - Code Deploy - ERROR - !!!!!!!!!! EXCEPTION !!!!!!!!!(535, b'5.7.8     Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z16-20020a170903019000b0019a97a4324dsm9818181plg.5 - gsmtp')Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/code-dployment/server/deploy.py", line 94, in send_email
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 729, in login
raise last_exception
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 720, in login
initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z16-20020a170903019000b0019a97a4324dsm9818181plg.5 - gsmtp')

2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
2023-03-09 11:54:00,797 - Code Deploy - ERROR - !!!!!!!!!! EXCEPTION !!!!!!!!!(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k17-20020aa790d1000000b005907716bf8bsm11097506pfk.60 - gsmtp')Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/code-dployment/server/deploy.py", line 94, in send_email
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 729, in login
raise last_exception
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 720, in login
initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k17-20020aa790d1000000b005907716bf8bsm11097506pfk.60 - gsmtp')
```

It needs to get the contents between two patterns.

Pattern1 = 'Received signal'

Pattern2 = 'Deployment finished'

Expected result:

```
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

I want to get an AWK command to use it in a bash script. I found a solution to filter the contents between two patterns by using the command below:

```
# awk '/Received signal/,/Deployment finished/' /tmp/result.log
```

It will print the whole matching lines of all occurrences, but, I need to filter it so it only prints the last occurrence of the matching pattern.

The above command's output is:

```
2023-03-08 11:12:44,306 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-08 11:12:44,306 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-08 11:12:44,306 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-08 11:12:44,307 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-08 11:13:31,782 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_12
2023-03-08 11:13:31,783 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_13
2023-03-08 11:13:32,553 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-08 11:13:32,554 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk and very similar to one of the scripts in [@terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739291/133219) but IMO just a bit more idiomatically awkish in use of awk's `condition { action }` body structure:

```
$ awk '
    /Received signal/ { f=1; rec="" }
    f { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    /Deployment finished/ { f=0 }
    END { if (f=="0") printf "%s", rec }
' file
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

The minor functional differences between this and @terdon's answer are:

1. This one will produce the desired record terminators in the unlikely event that you decide to set ORS to something different from RS (e.g. maybe you want to convert `RS='\r\n'` to `ORS='\n'`), while @terdon's will reproduce the RS value in most of the output with an ORS just at the end of it.
2. @terdon's would print a blank line if the input file doesn't contain any `Received signal` lines while this one wouldn't produce any output.
3. This one will only print the text between the delimiters if both delimiters exist in the input while @terdon's would print whatever follows a `Received signal` line even if no subsequent `Deployment finished` line is present.

Regarding `awk '/Received signal/,/Deployment finished/' /tmp/result.log` in your question - don't use range expressions, use a flag, see [is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk). As you can see in every answer posted so far that uses a range expression, it requires testing the same condition twice.

Comment: Heh, and I only even used `v=v RS $0` instead of just `v=v" "$0` thinking that you would come and correctly point out that for all I know, the RS wasn't a space! For what it's worth, this is better than mine in my opinion as well.

Comment: @terdon Yeah, it was the use of `RS` instead of `ORS` when building the **output** record that got my eye twitching a bit on that one :-). I'd just have commented but I wanted to showcase more the `condition { action }` structure anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Reverse the file, delete all lines not in the range `/Deployment finished/,/Received signal/`, and quit as soon as you match the end of that range of lines.  Then reverse the result.

```bash
tail -r file |
sed -e '/Deployment finished/,/Received signal/!d' -e '/Received signal/q' |
tail -r
```

GNU system users may want to use `tac` in place of `tail -r` above.

If you feel you need to use `awk` instead, replace the `sed` command in the pipeline above with

```bash
awk '/Deployment finished/,/Received signal/; /Received signal/ { exit }'
```

Output, given the data in the question:

```
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

Comment: Thank you, It is a nice idea.

I think you have a typo in the result, you mean the command "tac" not "tail".


>>> # tac file | sed -e '/Deployment finished/,/Received signal/!d' -e '/Received signal/q' | tac

Comment: @AmalPRamesh As you can see just after the initial command, I suggest that users that use GNU systems change `tail -r` to `tac`.  The `tail -r` command works the same way on macOS and other BSD systems as GNU `tac` on GNU systems.  As the user in the question did not say they were on any particular Unix, I made sure to mention both `tac` and `tail -r`.

Comment: @AmalPRamesh Please [read](https://man.openbsd.org/tail.1#r).

Answer (score 3):

A simple trick is to save each match in a variable, overwriting what was previously there, and then, at the end of the script, print the variable:

```
$ awk '{ 
         if(/Received signal/){k=1; v=$0} 
         else if(k==1){
           v=v RS $0; 
           if(/Deployment finished/){ k=0 }
         }
       } 
       END{ print v }' result.log
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

Or you could use `tac` to reverse the file and then print the first match:

```
$ tac result.log | 
   awk '/Deployment finished/,/Received signal/{
      print; 
      if(/Received signal/){ exit }
   }' | tac
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $k; my @v; for lines() { 
            if /Received \s signal/ {$k = 1; @v = $_} 
            elsif ($k == 1) { @v.push: $_ }; 
            if /Deployment \s finished/ {$k = 0}
            }; .put for @v;'  file
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Received message signal
2023-03-09 11:52:57,194 - Code Deploy - INFO - Branch is Testing
2023-03-09 11:52:57,195 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment started
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - Old version2_0_5_13
2023-03-09 11:53:58,246 - Code Deploy - INFO - New version2_0_5_14
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Permission fixed
2023-03-09 11:53:58,498 - Code Deploy - INFO - Deployment finished
```

The above code shamelessly follows @terdon's excellent `awk` code, but re-written in Raku. The key as (@terdon notes) is to over-write the "storing-variable" (in this case `@v` array) every time the opening `/Received \s signal/` regex is spotted. Here, because `lines` are loaded one-by-one into the `$_` topic variable, the code `@v = $_` is used.

If--upon reaching the end of the file--you don't want any return unless the closing `/Deployment \s finished/` is seen last (i.e. a "full-record" requirement), then change the final out`put` statement to:

```perl
.put if $k == 0 for @v;

#OR

.put unless $k == 1 for @v;
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/control.html#Control_flow
https://raku.org